# QuickBlox get presence of user which isn't in the contacts

Tags: java, android, quickblox

I'm developing android chat application using QuickBlox.. My app will be like : The user logs in and chooses any another user to chat with.. (Not in the roster).. I managed to get users using the following code :

```
retrieveAllUsersFromPage(1); 

private void retrieveAllUsersFromPage(int page){
    QBPagedRequestBuilder pagedRequestBuilder = new QBPagedRequestBuilder();
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPage(page);
    pagedRequestBuilder.setPerPage(100);

    QBUsers.getUsers(pagedRequestBuilder, this);
}

int userNumber = 1;

@Override
public void onSuccess(ArrayList<QBUser> users, Bundle params) {
    for(QBUser user : users){
        this.users.add(user);
        userNumber ++;
    }

    int currentPage = params.getInt(Consts.CURR_PAGE);
    int totalEntries = params.getInt(Consts.TOTAL_ENTRIES);

    if(userNumber < totalEntries){
        retrieveAllUsersFromPage(currentPage+1);
    }

}
```

but I wanna filter them to add only the available(online) users.. I can't find a way to do that.. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0):

With no roster you can use next trick with **user.lastRequestAt** field

http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Online.5COffline_status